# Why is Excel 2007 backwards?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I opened up Excel 2007 and this is what I see:

[image]

Where the row headings are on the right and the columns are backwards...

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: did you recently change any language settings?

Comment: I did.  I had hebrew there which i removed.

Comment: Hebrew keyboard layout or Hebrew as the primary user interface language (Hebrew is a right to left language, which is why you're having this problem.)  Hopefully now you'll be alright.

Comment: @wizlog - but i have removed Hebrew as an available language and its not turning back from left to right.

Comment: did you follow the instructions in my answer? Remember, you need to close Excel and (I'm not sure but...) all other Microsoft Office programs before changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click **Start**, point to **All Programs**, point to **Microsoft Office**, point to **Microsoft Office Tools**, and then click **2007 Microsoft Office system Language Settings**. [image: Where to find the Microsoft Office system Language Settings]
2. Click the **Display Language** tab.

   - *NOTE* The **Display Language** tab appears only after you have installed a 2007 Office release Single Language Pack or the Multi-Language Pack.
3. In the **Display 2007 Office release menus and dialog boxes in** list, click the language in which you want to display 2007 Office release programs. To display a right-to-left user interface, you must click one of the languages that are written from right to left (such as Arabic, Urdu, or Persian).  *[Similarly, to display a left-to-right user interface (what you're trying to do), make sure that you select a language with a left-to-right user interface]*
4. Click **OK**.

Comment: I don't see Tools Options in Excel 2007

Comment: Sorry, click the Orb, then click options.  From there go to the advanced tab, look for "display" (default direction), from there select left-to-right

Comment: I see "Excel Options" (not options). i do see the advanced section and i see a "display" section but i don't see anything about left to right.

Comment: @leora Ok, I'll include screenshots.

Comment: i think the issue is found here: http://forums.techarena.in/ms-office-support/1332979.htm.   it looks like Excel has a bug where it removes these settings.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts finally found a solution for Office 2007
If it's not available under Option you can fix it here:

1. Open VBA editor
2. In project pane Click on the impacted Worksheet
3. In Properties pane set DisplayRightToLeft = False